# Help on expressing a model

Tags: model, lme4-nlme, notation

I am a complete newbie in statistical modeling and I never got the opportunity to learn how to express a model in algebraic form and its respective matrix notation. I know how to define models in R code, but I do not understand how to write it in mathematic form, e.g. with β as the vector of a fixed effect. I am trying to find good literature on this topic, but have a hard time finding any. Does anyone know where can I learn this? Sorry if this is a basic and maybe inappropriate question here, and something that I should probably have learned long ago. However I have not had the need to use any "advanced" models until now.

As an example, I have a longitudinal dataset of biomass from an experiment. The subjects have been exposed of 3 different treatments (LOW, MED, HI) during 200 days, and measured repeatedly at 40 occasions. I have constructed a linear mixed model in R, with lme (from nlme package), with a autocorrelation structure (AR1) and a random intercept and slope:

```
Biomass.lme<-lme(Biomass~Treatment*Day,random=~Day|Subject,data=longterm, na.action=na.exclude,corr=corAR1(form=~Day|Flask))
```

Where Treatment is a factor and Day continuous variable. Hence, I am interested to see if the responses of the groups is dependent on the exposure time (i.e. the interaction of treatment and time).

I would be happy if someone could explain to me how this model would look in algebraic form and why, or provide me with some information on how to do express model.

Comment: Had you wanted to use a fixed effects model (generalized least squares with, for example, a continuous time AR1 covariance structure) and if you were a LaTeX user, the R `rms` package allows you to typeset the fitted model in algebraic form with the `latex(fit.object)` function.